# Maven command 'mvn clean test' causes build failure

Tags: java, maven

I've got a Maven project for a java application. The software versions I'm using are following:
Maven 3.6.3, Java 1.8.0_241.

I've got few junit tests within this Maven project, that I'm trying to run using the Maven "mvn" command. When I run the command "mvn clean test" on my Maven project to run my unit tests, I get below mentioned build failure.

```
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  02:48 min
[INFO] Finished at: 2020-02-21T09:37:00+05:30
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.22.2:test (default-test) on project Myproject-restapis: There are test failures.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] Please refer to F:\eclipseWorkspaces\my_project\target\surefire-reports for the individual test results.
[ERROR] Please refer to dump files (if any exist) [date].dump, [date]-jvmRun[N].dump and [date].dumpstream.
[ERROR] The forked VM terminated without properly saying goodbye. VM crash or System.exit called?
[ERROR] Command was cmd.exe /X /C "C:\jdk1.8.0_241\jre\bin\java -jar C:\Users\mukul\AppData\Local\Temp\surefire4895736141834565700\surefirebooter185004090178601900.jar C:\Users\mukul\AppData\Local\Temp\surefire4895736141834565700 2020-02-21T09-34-41_267-jvmRun1 surefire413243705282645614tmp surefire_01613681214173913161tmp"
[ERROR] Process Exit Code: 0
[ERROR] Crashed tests:
[ERROR] com.example.test.SampleTest
[ERROR] org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireBooterForkException: The forked VM terminated without properly saying goodbye. VM crash or System.exit called?
[ERROR] Command was cmd.exe /X /C "C:\jdk1.8.0_241\jre\bin\java -jar C:\Users\mukul\AppData\Local\Temp\surefire4895736141834565700\surefirebooter185004090178601900.jar C:\Users\mukul\AppData\Local\Temp\surefire4895736141834565700 2020-02-21T09-34-41_267-jvmRun1 surefire413243705282645614tmp surefire_01613681214173913161tmp"
[ERROR] Process Exit Code: 0
[ERROR] Crashed tests:
[ERROR] com.example.test.SampleTest
[ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.booterclient.ForkStarter.fork(ForkStarter.java:669)
[ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.booterclient.ForkStarter.run(ForkStarter.java:282)
[ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.booterclient.ForkStarter.run(ForkStarter.java:245)
[ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.AbstractSurefireMojo.executeProvider(AbstractSurefireMojo.java:1183)
[ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.AbstractSurefireMojo.executeAfterPreconditionsChecked(AbstractSurefireMojo.java:1011)
[ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.AbstractSurefireMojo.execute(AbstractSurefireMojo.java:857)
[ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
[ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:210)
[ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:156)
[ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:148)
[ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
[ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
[ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
[ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
[ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:305)
[ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:192)
[ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:105)
[ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:957)
[ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:289)
[ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:193)
[ERROR]         at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
[ERROR]         at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
[ERROR]         at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
[ERROR]         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
[ERROR]         at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:282)
[ERROR]         at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:225)
[ERROR]         at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:406)
[ERROR]         at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:347)
```

I've looked a lot on web about the above mentioned issue, but haven't been able to solve this for few days now.

The command 'mvn clean install -DskipTests' runs fine for me, and I get build success.

Can anyone please try to provide solution for the above mentioned issue, with the Maven command 'mvn clean test'.

Comment: as the error says there are test failures in SampleTest. Cannot say the exact reason without looking at the code.

Comment: Can you try with different version of maven surefire plugin.

Comment: @kann: The maven surefire plugin that I used, when I pasted the original build failure log, was of version 2.22.2 (which is the latest released version). As per your comment, I also tried with maven surefire plugin version 3.0.0-M4 which is the latest available in the maven central repository, which also generates the same error for me.

Comment: @Chiran: the same test cases for me, run fine within eclipse's maven IDE. I don't think that, there's any issue with my unit tests code.

Comment: I would read the whole logging output cause I suppose there is more output there. I suppose one of the tests is failing ...check this first ....

Comment: sorry, can't post the whole (real) logging output. it contains proprietary project naming. it'd be great, if someone can help further debugging this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I had the exactly same issue, and the way that I sorted it out was to configure log properly for my tests..

I have a multi-module project, and I added a logback-test.xml in the root my my parent project and pointed my maven-surefire-plugin to load this file. See the config bellow:

```
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <argLine>-Dlogback.configurationFile=${project.basedir}/../logback-test.xml</argLine>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

In the logbook-test.xml I reduced a lot of the logs and added some library packages to print from WARN level.

```
<logger name="org.apache.solr" level="WARN" />
```

**Important**: Make sure you replace all System.out.println with log.debug